# How to move a printed char in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am close to finishing my project, which moves printed cars in a roundabout, but I have two big problems:

- When generating a character with a rand and this character moves forward (for example its intial position was `[5][0]` and now he is at `[5][1]`), how to generate another character in `[5][0]` every time the initial character move?
- My roundabout have two ways to come like in real life, but when I make my program and execute it, both cars from this two ways don't move at the same time, my program move the car from the right side and when he is arrived, it starts moving the left one

My roundabout in image:
[My roundabout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59dEi.jpg)

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NB_L 43
#define NB_C 90

typedef struct array ARRAY;
struct array {
        int matrice1 [NB_L][NB_C];
        int matrice2 [NB_L][NB_C];
};

// Les prototypes des fonctions
void myDelay (float i);
void roadMap1 (ARRAY *vehicule);
void roadMap2 (ARRAY *vehicule);
void initCarsFromWest (ARRAY *vehicule);
void deplacement1 (ARRAY *vehicule);
void deplacement2 (ARRAY *vehicule);
void movingCarsFromWest (ARRAY *vehicule);

// Fais une pause de l'application durant i seconds
void myDelay (float i) {

        clock_t start, end;

        start = clock ();
        while (((end = clock ()) - start) <= i * CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

// Fonction qui initialise chaque case du giratoire dans un tableau
void roadMap1 (ARRAY *vehicule) {

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        // NB_L de NB_C
        for (i = 0; i < NB_L; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < NB_C; j++) {
                        vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] = 0;
                }
        }

        // La partie nord de notre giratoire.
        for (i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][40] = 20;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][42] = 13;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][44] = 20;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][46] = 13;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][48] = 20;
        }

        //La partie est du giratoire.
        for (j = 61; j < 89; j++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [17][j] = 16;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [19][j] = 15;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [21][j] = 12;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [23][j] = 15;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [25][j] = 16;
        }

        // La partie sud du giratoire.
        for (i = 29; i < 42; i++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][40] = 20;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][42] = 13;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][44] = 20;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][46] = 13;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][48] = 20;
        }

        //La partie ouest du giratoire.
        for (j = 0; j < 28; j++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [17][j] = 16;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [19][j] = 15;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [21][j] = 12;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [23][j] = 15;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [25][j] = 16;
        }

        // Le giratoire.
        for (i = 15; i < 17; i++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][28] = 20;
        }
        for (i = 26; i < 28; i++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][28] = 20;
        }

        for (j = 29; j < 40; j++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [14][j] = 16;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [28][j] = 16;
        }

        for (j = 49; j < 60; j++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [14][j] = 16;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [28][j] = 16;
        }

        for (i = 15; i < 17; i++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][60] = 20;
        }

        for (i = 26; i < 28; i++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [i][60] = 20;
        }

        // Le centre de notre giratoire.
        for (j = 35; j < 54; j++) {
                vehicule -> matrice1 [17][j] = 11;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [18][j] = 11;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [19][j] = 11;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [20][j] = 11;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [21][j] = 11;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [22][j] = 11;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [23][j] = 11;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [24][j] = 11;
                vehicule -> matrice1 [25][j] = 11;
        }

        // Les "coins" du centre de notre giratoire.
        vehicule -> matrice1 [17][28] = 21;
        vehicule -> matrice1 [25][28] = 18;

        vehicule -> matrice1 [14][28] = 19;
        vehicule -> matrice1 [28][28] = 17;

        vehicule -> matrice1 [14][40] = 21;
        vehicule -> matrice1 [28][40] = 18;

        vehicule -> matrice1 [14][48] = 17;
        vehicule -> matrice1 [28][48] = 19;

        vehicule -> matrice1 [14][60] = 18;
        vehicule -> matrice1 [28][60] = 21;

        vehicule -> matrice1 [17][60] = 17;
        vehicule -> matrice1 [25][60] = 19;
}

// Fonction qui sert à afficher notre giratoire
void roadMap2 (ARRAY *vehicule) {

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        // NB_L de NB_C
        for (i = 0; i < NB_L; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < NB_C; j++) {
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 0) {
                                printf(" ");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 1) {
                                printf("N");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 2) {
                                printf("E");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 3) {
                                printf("S");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 4) {
                                printf("W");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 11) {
                                printf("█");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 12) {
                                printf("■");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 13) {
                                printf("|");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 14) {
                                printf("╬");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 15) {
                                printf("-");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 16) {
                                printf("═");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 17) {
                                printf("╚");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 18) {
                                printf("╗");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 19) {
                                printf("╔");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 20) {
                                printf("║");
                        }
                        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [i][j] == 21) {
                                printf("╝");
                        }
                } printf("\n");
        }
}

// Fonction qui initialise les deux voitures partant de l'ouest
void initCarsFromWest (ARRAY *vehicule) {

        // char direction [] = {'N', 'S', 'W', 'E'};
        vehicule -> matrice1 [22][0] = rand () % 5;
        vehicule -> matrice1 [24][0] = rand () % 5;
}

// Déplacement sur la ligne 24
void deplacement1 (ARRAY *vehicule) {

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
                if (vehicule -> matrice1 [24][j] == 1 || vehicule -> matrice1 [24][j] == 2 || vehicule -> matrice1 [24][j] == 3 || vehicule -> matrice1 [24][j] == 4) {
                        vehicule -> matrice1 [24][j+1] = vehicule -> matrice1 [24][j];
                        vehicule -> matrice1 [24][j] = 0;
                }

                myDelay (0.1);
                system ("clear");
                roadMap2 (vehicule);
        }
}

// Déplacement sur la ligne 22
void deplacement2 (ARRAY *vehicule) {

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
                if (vehicule -> matrice1 [22][j] == 1 || vehicule -> matrice1 [22][j] == 2 || vehicule -> matrice1 [22][j] == 3 || vehicule -> matrice1 [22][j] == 4) {
                        vehicule -> matrice1 [22][j+1] = vehicule -> matrice1 [22][j];
                        vehicule -> matrice1 [22][j] = 0;
                }

                myDelay (0.1);
                system ("clear");
                roadMap2 (vehicule);
        }
}

void movingCarsFromWest (ARRAY *vehicule) {

        roadMap1 (vehicule);
        initCarsFromWest (vehicule);

        int i = 0, j = 0;

        // Nord
        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [24][0] == 1) {
                deplacement1 (vehicule);
        }
        // Est
        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [24][0] == 2) {
                deplacement1 (vehicule);
        }
        // Sud
        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [24][0] == 3) {
                deplacement1 (vehicule);
        }
        // Ouest
        if (vehicule -> matrice1 [24][0] == 4) {
                deplacement1 (vehicule);
        }

// Nord
            if (vehicule -> matrice1 [22][0] == 1) {
                    deplacement2 (vehicule);
            }
            // Est
            if (vehicule -> matrice1 [22][0] == 2) {
                    deplacement2 (vehicule);
            }
            // Sud
            if (vehicule -> matrice1 [22][0] == 3) {
                    deplacement2 (vehicule);
            }
            // Ouest
            if (vehicule -> matrice1 [22][0] == 4) {
                    deplacement2 (vehicule);
            }

        roadMap2 (vehicule);
}

int main (int argc, int **argv) {

ARRAY *vehicule;
        srand (time (NULL));

        while (1) {
                movingCarsFromWest (vehicule);
                system ("clear");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a character once its printed to STDOUT. You can use [ANSI controls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to erase printed characters.

You can delete individual characters, lines, or erase the entire screen and reprint it.
Here's an example of erasing a line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("hello\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);

    //clear from cursor to the beginning of the line
    printf("\033[1K");
    //move cursor to the beginning of the line
    printf("\033[F");

    printf("world!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this answers your question...

Comment: Forgive me, but wouldn't `roadMap2` inherently handle that issue by iterating `i = 0; i < NB_L` and `j = 0; j < NB_C` and repainting the entire area each time it is called?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't spend much time looking at his code because it doesn't compile (vehicule isn't defined). I just answered the title question.

Comment: Sorry vehicule is now defined :) And David yes i tried but that's not working :(

Comment: What do you want to know? I told you "How to move a printed char in C". What other questions do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Problem number 1 is your code crashes immediately. It crashes because of this:

```
ARRAY *vehicule;
while (1) {
    movingCarsFromWest (vehicule);
```

You don't initialize `vehicule` so it points to a random location in memory, which causes undefined behavior. What you need is to actually allocate an `ARRAY`, not a pointer to an `ARRAY`, and then pass its address, like this:

```
ARRAY vehicule;
while (1) {
    movingCarsFromWest (&vehicule);
```

Making this change at least allows your program to run. I can't tell if it's producing correct results because you haven't defined what the correct results are, but you should be able to make forward progress from here.

Comment: Thx i made the change but still the same effect :(

Comment: @BrandonCarvalho And what effect is that? You need to describe what results you're expecting and what results you're getting, and that description needs to be in your question. In any case, the error I pointed out above is a serious one that you must fix before you fix anything else.